# Regex to get string between single or double quotes even if it's empty

Tags: php, regex

Below is the REGEX which I am trying:

```
/((?<![\\\\])['"])((?:.(?!(?<![\\\\])\\1))*.?)\\1/
```

Here this is the text which I am giving

```
val1=""val2>"2022-11-16 10:19:20"
```

I need blank expressions like for val1 as well,
i.e. I need something like below in matches

```
""
2022-11-16 10:19:20
```

If I change the text to something like below, I am getting proper output

```
val2>"2022-11-16 10:19:20"val1=""
```

Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: If the contents of the quotes is empty you want the quotes, but if the contents aren't empty you just want the contents without the quotes around it?

Comment: Otherwise, wouldn't `/"(.*?)"/g` do?

Answer (score 2):

Use alternatives to match the two cases.

One alternative matches the pair of quotes, the other uses lookarounds to match the inside of two quotes.

```
""|(?<=")[^"]+(?=")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern, this part `(?:.(?!(?<![\\])\1))*` first matches any character and then it asserts that what is to the right is not a group 1 value without an escape `\`

So in this string `""val2>"` your whole pattern matches `"` with the character class `["']` and then it matches `"` again with the `.` From the position after that match, it is true that what is to the right is not the group 1 value without a preceding `\` and that is why that match is `""val2>"` instead of `""`

---

If the second example string [does give you a proper output](https://regex101.com/r/ttrqaz/1), you could reverse the dot and first do the assertiong in the repeating part of the pattern, and omit matching an optional char `.?`

Note that the backslash does not have to be in square brackets.

```
(?<!\\)(['"])((?:(?!(?<!\\)\1).)*+)\1
```

See the updated [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/thiymY/1).